# Unable to convert the IST to UTC

Tags: java, java-8

date= "04-03-2019 15:30:00" PM and the UTC should be "04-03-2019 10:01:00" AM but I am getting wrong time.

```
date= "04-03-2019 15:30:00"
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").parse(date);
```

Comment: `z` in the pattern that you are parsing implies that the timezone is *already* UTC, which you have just told us it isn't.

Comment: Same code is working for CST format